# Firebase - Retrieving and storing data in array with callbacks

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I'm want to use Firebase callbacks to retrieve data from my realtime database, store it in an array, then use that data for data visualization purposes. But when I log the console for the array, it returns empty. I referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323) in an attempt to understand/fix my error, but I'm still having a lot of trouble.

```
var genderData=[];
// Get counter values.
function getData(){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('counters');

    return ref.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((element) => {
            genderData.push(element.val()['Male']);
        });
        return genderData;
    });
}

console.log(genderData);
```

My console shows:

[image]

Eventually, I want to be able to use my array to produce a chart with the Chart.js library:

```
// Bar graph displaying the total number of students by gender.
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart4").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Male", "Female", "Non-Binary", "Other", "Unspecified"],
        datasets: [{
            data: genderData,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Total Students by Gender'
        },
        legend:{
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

I've been working on this problem for hours, with no solution. All I want is to create a simple array with my database data, but I've had so much trouble. I really hope someone can help me find an elegant solution.

**EDIT**:

A bit of my database structure, just in case:

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you are pushing the value to your array, why are you also returning it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase loads data asynchronously. This means that any code that needs access to the data, must be inside the `then()` callback, or must use a `then()` callback of its own.

With your current definition of `getData`, you can call it and use the data with:

```
getData().then((data) => {
  console.log("In callback");
  console.log(data);
  console.log(genderData);
})
console.log("Outside callback");
console.log(genderData);
```

If you run this code, you'll see:

> Outside callback
>
> []
>
> Inside callback
>
> [ item1, item2, ... ]
>
> [ item1, item2, ... ]

The things to note here:

1. the `Outside callback` code runs *before* the `Inside callback` code, which is probably not what you expected.
2. the code outside of the callback runs, the array is still empty. Only once the code inside the callback has run, does the array contain data.
3. inside the callback, the `genderData` and the `data` are the same. This is because you `return genderData` in the callback, which is then bubbled up to the `then()` method.

The final solution for you is that the code that creates the chart (which is where you need the data), should be *inside* one of the `then` callbacks so that it gets called once the data has loaded. For example:

```
getData().then((data) => {
   var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'bar',
     data: {
        labels: ["Male", "Female", "Non-Binary", "Other", "Unspecified"],
        datasets: [{
            data: data,
            ...
```

Comment: This makes sense. But I think now I've run into a different problem: when I log the data as you suggested, all of my values are undefined (and there are far too many values -- 54 when there should be 13).  What could be causing this? I've included a screenshot of my database structure, just in case.

Comment: My guess is that you call `getData()` multiple times, and each time you add all items to `genderData`. But it's just a guess. Note that none of this has anything to do with the chart.js library itself, so I recommend looking at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reduce the scope of the problem.

Comment: Yes, I believe it was the `forEach` loop. I removed it and simply did `genderData.push(snapshot.val()['Male']);`, and now my console seems to be logging as expected (I hope). Here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/Dil6ojT